On update time Sequelize hook not trigger
I have add beforeCreate and beforeUpdate hook in sequelize model
hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (Coach) => {
        Coach.password = getBcryptHashPassword(Coach.password);
      },
      beforeUpdate: (Coach) => {
        if (Coach.password)
          Coach.password = getBcryptHashPassword(Coach.password);
      },
    },

Create time hook treigger properly
But when I can update service hook not trigger
exports.update = async (data, conditions) => {
  return Model.update(data,conditions );
};

This is my update service
I want trigger beforeUpdate hook on call update service

Same issue i am facing

If you want to use in controller


exports.update = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await service.update(req.body, {
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
        academyId: req.user.id,
      },
      individualHooks: true
    });


    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Update successfully.",
      affectedRows: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};




The issue is due to the 'individualHooks' flag not being set to 'true' while triggering the update query as some methods do not emit individual hooks by default.
To resolve this issue, you can modify the 'update' service function to include  'individualHooks' flag set to 'true'.
Here is how you can do it:
exports.update = async (data, condition) => {
     return Model.update(data, {...condition, individualHooks: true});
};

